# Employment and Education Documents with IM5252e

Tags: visas, canada

Do you upload previous employment and education documents with the Canadian visa application? I have read it on multiple websites that people attach these documents but cannot find the same information on the official website.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what IM5252e is supposed to be. It doesn't seem to correspond to any official Canadian document.

The [actual document checklist](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5881E.pdf) provided by the High Commission of Canada in New Delhi, and applicable to residents of India, does not mention anything about previous employers, and only mentions education in the context of a student visa. You do need to include information about your current employer, such as pay slips, a NOC from your employer, etc.

Note that if you don't currently live in India, you should check Canada's immigration web site and [enter the country in which you reside](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp) to get country-specific information.